# spring bean: good XML data structure for many classes?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am working on a demo with Java Spring Bean. I have a structure in the applicationContext.xml. Something like that:

```
<bean id="Transfer1" class="bank.Transfer">
    <property name="id" value="1" />
    <property name="firstname" value="Thomas" />
    <property name="lastname" value="Bäcker" />
    <property name="transferdate" value="2016-11-15" />
    <property name="amount" value="300" />
</bean>

<bean id="Transfer2" class="bank.Transfer">
    <property name="id" value="2" />
    <property name="firstname" value="Bob" />
    <property name="lastname" value="Sapp" />
    <property name="transferdate" value="2016-12-01" />
    <property name="amount" value="2700" />
</bean>
 //   
 // followed by Transfer3, Transfer4...
 //
```

I am wondering if there is a better solution, data structure for this. May be something where i can put all Transfers in one Bean instead a long list of Beans. Thx for any advice!

Comment: This really sounds like a job for a database.

Comment: Why you are hard coding the values in xml ?

Comment: It is just a demo that s why i am not using a database. There are max. 8 records. As i m pretty new to spring i have thought that there is may be a better solution. Anyway thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you do not have many classes. You have many instances of the same class...

There is nothing bad with what you done, just because you need 8 instances of the same class with different values only for demo.

If you'd like to combine them into one "holder" bean as collection (array, list, set, map...) you can create your own class (i.e. `bank.AllTransfers`) with property as any collections (array, list,set,map) and define another bean like

```
<bean id="allTransfers" class="bank.AllTransfers">
  <property name="transfersCollection">
        <list>
            <ref bean="Transfer1"/>
            <ref bean="Transfer2"/>
        </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Also take a look at Spring Util package (namespace is `http://www.springframework.org/schema/util`). there are bunch of elements to do the same without another wrapper bean like:

```
<util:list name="transfersList" list-class="java.util.ArrayList" value-type="bank.Transfer">
    <ref bean="Transfer1">
    <ref bean="Transfer2">
</util:list>
```

In that case you will have just a bean of class `java.util.ArrayList` you can reference to from another beans i.e.

```
<bean id="allTransfers" class="bank.AllTransfers">
  <property name="transfersCollection">
        <ref bean="transfersList"/>
  </property>
</bean>
```

for those examples you have to keep your 8 beans definitions "as is".
Of course you can put them right in your `list` like:

```
<bean id="allTransfers" class="bank.AllTransfers">
  <property name="transfersCollection">
        <list>
           <bean id="Transfer1" class="bank.Transfer">
             <property name="id" value="1" />
             <property name="firstname" value="Thomas" />
             ...
           </bean>
           <bean id="Transfer2" class="bank.Transfer">
              <property name="id" value="2" />
              <property name="firstname" value="Bob" />
              ...
           </bean>
        </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

there are many-many possibilities...

PS. but if you still want to keep your 8 beans construction in the Spring context (not from DB, external .properties file ...) you have to have them defined anyway.